# PubNub and Python's multiprocessing.Process not compatible?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pubnub

I'm trying to receive messages from PubNub inside a process using Python's multiprocessing.Process package (Python 3.5 on Raspbian 9 - Stretch).

The following works perfectly as a standalone program or within a thread using Python's threading package.  However, it doesn't work with multiprocessing.Process.

Am I missing something or is PubNub's SubscribeListener not compatible with Python's multiprocessing package?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub, SubscribeListener
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration

import multiprocessing
import time

def PN_func():
    pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
    pnconfig.subscribe_key = 'sub-mykey'
    pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

    print('Pubnub multiprocess subscriber initiated...')

    class Listener(SubscribeListener):
        def message(self, pubnub, data):
            print("From Multiprocess function message: ", data.message)

    pubnub.add_listener(Listener())
    pubnub.subscribe().channels('my_channel').execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp = multiprocessing.Process(target=PN_func)
    mp.start()
    mp.join()
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than *doesn't work*? Do you get an error message? What behaviour do you expect and what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: @BoarGules I have a separate program that generates a message every four seconds.  If I run the above (using my personal sub key of course) under a thread or a standalone process I get my initiation print message and then every four seconds it prints out the message.    The above simply prints my initiation message to the terminal "Pubnub multiprocess subscriber initiated..." and then the program terminates returning back to the Linux shell prompt.  No error message is presented.

Comment: @FarNorth I tested your code and indeed yes, it **does exit when using Multiprocessing**.  However, it does not exist when run without Multiprocessing.

Comment: Added answer that should work very  well for your needs.  If anything is missing let me know and we can add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub and Python Multiprocessing

I was unable to get the SDK to process synchronous requests inside a multiprocessing worker.  However the following trick works very well:

### Using Multiprocessing and PubNub Together

Simple `example.py` file contains the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests

SUB_KEY  = 'demo'
CHANNELS = ['my_channel']

def main():
    mp = multiprocessing.Process(target=subscriber)
    mp.start()
    mp.join()

def subscriber():
    timetoken = '0' ## pointer to last message received
    while True:
        url = "/".join([
            'https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe'
        ,   SUB_KEY
        ,   ",".join(CHANNELS)
        ,   '0'
        ,   timetoken
        ])

        print(url)

        response  = requests.get(url)
        data      = response.json()
        messages  = data[0]
        timetoken = data[1]

        print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

#### Output of Multiprocessing Child Process

```
> python example.py 
https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/my_channel/0/0
[[], u'15336927707090912']
https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/my_channel/0/15336927707090912
[[{u'text': u'hey'}], u'15336927943808959']
https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/my_channel/0/15336927943808959
[[{u'text': u'hey'}], u'15336927945476647']
https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/my_channel/0/15336927945476647
[[{u'text': u'hey'}], u'15336927946996529']
https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/my_channel/0/15336927946996529
[[{u'text': u'hey'}], u'15336927948441519']
https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/my_channel/0/15336927948441519
[[{u'text': u'hey'}], u'15336927950007602']
https://ps.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/my_channel/0/15336927950007602
```

Comment: @Stephen_Blum  thanks for getting back to me with a solution that works.  Are there plans to update SubscribeListener to work with multiprocessing.Process?

Comment: It's something to do with `request_sync` vs `request_async`.  I'll add the details about the bug and submit to the git repo.

Comment: This has been submitted and we'll be working on providing a patch.